# Post array using http flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

This is the error that I get when I run my code.

```
E/flutter (21412): 
#0      CastMap.forEach.<anonymous closure> (dart:_internal/cast.dart:288:25) E/flutter (21412): 
#1     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:397:8) E/flutter (21412): 
#2 CastMap.forEach (dart:_internal/cast.dart:287:13) E/flutter (21412):
#3      mapToQuery (package:http/src/utils.dart:17:7) E/flutter (21412): 
#4      Request.bodyFields=(package:http/src/request.dart:137:12) /flutter (21412): 
#5     BaseClient._sendUnstreamed package:http/src/base_client.dart:85:17) E/flutter (21412): 
#6      BaseClient.post (package:http/src/base_client.dart:32:7) E/flutter (21412): 
#7     post.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:70:16) E/flutter (21412): 
#8      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:166:20) E/flutter (21412): 
#9      post (package:http/http.dart:69:5) E/flutter (21412):
#10     _preferenceState.add_preference (package:hulue/ui/cv_from/components/preference.dart:441:26)
```

Here is the code that I use which throws the error in my case:

```
List commentList = ['1','2','3'];
  post_preference() async {
    print(commentList);
    var response = await http.post(
      "$uri/subscriber/add_preference",
      body: {'category':commentList},
      headers: <String, String>{
        //'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        "Authorization": "Bearer $token"
      },
    ); 
  print(response.statusCode);
    // print(response.body);
    var jsonResponse = await convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(json.decode(jsonResponse));

    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      print(response.statusCode);

      // print(jsonResponse);
      // print(response);
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "successful add ",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
      );
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        this.context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => myCv()),
      );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
body: json.encode(body: {'category':commentList}),
```